# Change script location on publish

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I often have to do web development without a reliable internet connection (e.g. on the train). I have all external javascript files locally and have set up IIS to serve them when I reference like this

```
<script src="http://external.dev/somescript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now when I publish my website (or ideally at any point in time) I would like the `external.dev` to change to `external.com` (or a domain of my choosing). I'd like some sort of switch to flick back and forth between local and external on demand.

I assume this would be a common problem (?) so is there any techniques/tools that can help me? I could of course be approaching this the wrong way and there is an easier way to achieve my goal.

Any ideas?

Comment: For normal webforms I load my scripts from javascript, specifically jquery getScript calls which is printed out onto page by a client script manager which resolves if we're currently in debug or publish mode via project settings. In MVC just bundle config changes. Let me know if i need to elaborate on either.

Comment: Thanks @f0x. I was thinking there might be a solution that didn't depend on the design (webforms/mvc/whatever). I might have a simple html page that references a script (no code behind) that would change depending on an IDE setting. I guess this isn't really Visual Studio specific but thought there might be an answer for Visual Studio. I'll think a bit more on this.